# Realizar un update a un campo tipo xml en sql

Tags: sql

Quiero hacer un "update" a un campo de tipo xml en sql. Ejemplo:
Si tengo una columna DummyColumn de tipo xml en la tabla DummyTable con el siguiente xml:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="DummyKey1" value="10" />
  <add key="DummyKey2" value="20" />
  <add key="DummyKey3" value="30" />
  <add key="DummyKey4" value="40" />
<appSettings>
```

¿Como hago para actualizar el valor de value de DummyKey4 a 4?

Tras varias búsuqedas en google he intentado:

```
Update DummyTable 
set DummyColumn.modify('replace value of (/appSettings/@DummyKey4)[1] with "1"')
```

Se ejecuta correctamente pero no me cambia el valor.
El resultado esperado sería:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="DummyKey1" value="10" />
  <add key="DummyKey2" value="20" />
  <add key="DummyKey3" value="30" />
  <add key="DummyKey4" value="1" />
<appSettings>
```

Pero no me funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es:

```
UPDATE DummyTable 
SET DummyColumn.modify('replace value of 
(/appSettings/add/@value)[2] with "1"')
where ID = 3
```

[Xml data modification lenguaje](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-modification-language-xml-dml?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con una sintaxis como esta:

```
Update DummyTable set DummyColumn.modify('replace value of (/appSettings/add[@key=("DummyKey4")]/value/text()) with "4"')
```

Comment: Gracias. Con: "Update DummyTable set DummyColumn.modify('replace value of (/appSettings/add[@key=("DummyKey4")]/value/text()) with "4"') where id=3". Me da el siguiente error: "Mens. 2337, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 4
XQuery [DUMMYTABLE.DUMMYCOLUMN.modify()]: El destino de 'replace' debe ser como máximo un nodo. Se encontró 'text *'"

Comment: Hola, volviendo a revisar tengo una alternativa de como Reemplazar el valor de un atributo de nodo, use: Update DummyTable set DummyColumn.modify('replace value of (/appSettings/add[@key=("DummyKey4")]/@value)[1] with "4"'). 
aquí la [guía](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2738/examples-of-using-xquery-to-update-xml-data-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Así sí... Es justo la respuesta que publiqué ayer! :-) Gracias.